# Excel interop not coping from chosen range to cell

Tags: c#, excel, range, interop, cell

looking for help. Im new to programing, using C#.

Every time i run this code i get an error, it wont let me copy the chosen range from sheet 1 to sheet 2. the files open but an error comes up with exception.

Please help[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jK3Jy.png)

no idea what to try

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please reserve the use  of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. Please read [ask] and [edit] your question to add formatted code. For more information, please see the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/20153035), along with [this website](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Answer (score 0):

"A1" is a cell, not a range. You should set, for example `data.Copy(sheet2.Range["A1:C3"])`